# How to enable particular input fields with Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

[image]
this is a sample of cart page generated from html code  with  Angular 5

```
 <div *ngFor="let cart of carts; let i=index" class="panel" 
    id="product-panel">

  //some other lines

 <div class="panel-foot col-xs-12">    
        <div class="col-md-8 btns-group">
          <button   type="button" class="btn btn-default col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Remove</button>
          <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> checkout</button>
          <button (click)="edit(i)" type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> Edit</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class=" qty  col-xs-12">  

              <input [disabled]="!disable" id="qty-number" type="number" value="{{quantity}}" class="float-right col-md-3 col-xs-8 ">
               <div class="float-right plus-minus">
                 <div class="plus" (click)="plus()">
                   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                 </div>

                 <div class="minus" (click)="minus()">
                   <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                 </div>
               </div>

             </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

By default qty1&qty2 are disabled i want when the user click on edit inn the first product just qty1 is enable and so one.
I have tried many methods but all qty are enabled

How i can do this?

Comment: you seem to share the `disable` variable for both inputs. Try having this disable variable as an attribute of your cart. Same goes with the `quantity` variable as your value. Otherwise, both `quantity` and `disable` fields will be the shared for all carts. Then you'll be able to do `<input [disabled]="!cart.qtyDisabled" value="{{cart.quantity}}" />`

Comment: can you explain more with code please? @JonathanHamel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an actual answer to add a piece of code. The variable `disabled` and variable `quantity` is currently shared among all your carts. To avoid this, you'll have to define your cart class as such

```
export class Cart {
    quantity: number;
    qtyDisabled: boolean;
    // other fields

    constructor() {
        this.quantity = 15;
        this.qtyDisabled = true;
    }
}
```

and use it in your template like so

```
<div *ngFor="let cart of carts">

    <button (click)="edit(cart)"> Edit </button>
    <input [disabled]="cart.qtyDisabled" [(ngModel)]="cart.quantity" />
</div>
```

This way, each instance of your cart will have its own disabled and value attribute. I also suggest you to use the NgModel two way binding https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel within your angular template to bind input value change to your cart model.